# How to change the base image of configurable product by selecting the dropdown value?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I have created an attribute `variants` and added it in an `attribute set`. It is created to be used for configurable products.After creating a configurable product with this attribute set, the attribute `variants`is displayed in product details page as dropdown. But the base image is not changed when any value from the dropdown is selected. I gave the labels for the images too. But its not changing.

Is there any other thing that I have to do in order to change the base image when the dropdown value is selected in configurale products?
Somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

By Default this is not feature provided by magento until you use `swatch` system in magento , But for this purpose Our Moderator @Marius Has created a very good extension that you can use.

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

after installing this extension just go to

`System->Configuration-> Catalog->Easylife Switcher ->  Switch product images` change this setting as per your requirement.

And also `enable` that extension

Answer (score 0):

If you enable default swatch image functionality in the admin (system->catalog->configurable swatches->enabled->yes) and assign different base images to each of simple associated products (for example T-shirts of different colors), these images will change when variation is chosen.